# ASP.NET MVC localization of separated model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I try to localize properties of my model which is separated dll in my asp.net mvc project. I use `DisplayAttribute` for this:

```
[Display(Name = "InputDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
```

Resource files are created in model project and have public modifier.

When I use model with this property in view I see `InputDate` instead of value of this resource key. I think I didn't take into account something related with model assembly.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using GetMetadata ()??

Comment: Just to check during debugging

Comment: Try to follow my solution in below

Comment: Here is a guide for your solution: http://www.codedigest.com/posts/29/using-resource-file-for-dataannotations-display-attribute-with-multi-language-support-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: I've already seen that and done all these things
I can't find example where model is a separate dll as mine

Comment: Ok, try to remove this attribute ([DataType(DataType.Date)]) from your model.Than rebuild again

Comment: Some properties of this class have no this attribute and have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

In Model:

```
[Display(Name = "InputDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
```

1. Define ResourceType of the attribute so it looks for a resource
2. Define Name of the attribute which is used for the key of resource,
   you can use nameof for strong typed support instead of
   hard coding the key.
3. Set the culture of current thread in the controller.

> Resource.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("YourLocal");

4. Set the accessibility of the resource to public
   [image]
5. Display the label in cshtml like this

> `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateStart )`

You have to define resource key in project resources (.resx) file with 
specific localized value.

That is all!

Comment: The first step isn't clear. Do you mean create resource file? I've already done it. And all another steps too, besides the second.

Comment: Set Resources (.resx) file as public. I mean 'Access Modifier' should be set as public

Comment: It's done too. I changed custom tool of resource file to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

Comment: I've edited my post and add info about project where I created resource files. It is model project. Maybe it's important...

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!
After couple hours of debugging I figured out the root cause of my issue related with old code for handling model assembly attributes where ResourceType is ignored.
Sorry for your time spending!